# How to add a row in a itext PdfPTable dynamically?

Tags: java, itext

I have to create a pdf using itext which will contain a button, when clicked should add a row in an existing `PdfPTable`. I wrote some code to create a `PushbuttonField`. While trying to set action I can only find `PdfAction.javaScript`. I am not able to figure out how to add a row in a table. I tried searching online but all I could find is `PdfAction.javaScript`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you won't be able to do that. As soon as someone can press that button, there is no `PdfPTable` anymore. (The `PdfPTable` exists only while generating the pdf using iText, in the final pdf there only are the contents of the table arranged on the page with some lines inbetween.) Your requirement cannot be implemented in pure PDF  (or only in a very limited way by e.g. having a few additional table rows as invisible optional content). It can be implemented in some XFA form enclosed in the pdf but XFA forms have meanwhile become deprecated in ISO 32000-2.

Comment: The OP is confusing PDF with HTML. This question is invalid.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie No I am not confused. I have a pdf file which contains the buttons, when clicked it will add rows. But the code to create such files is not available or lost. So my task is to write the code for it.

Comment: That's an XFA file. It's not created using code (which explains why you can find that code). It's created using Adobe LiveCycle Designer. The content doesn't consist of PDF syntax; it's an XML file wrapped in a PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a PDF file, you draw text, lines and shapes to a canvas. That is also what happens when you add a `PdfPTable` to a `Document`. If you look at the syntax of the PDF page, you won't recognize a table. You'll find text (the content of the cells), lines (the borders), and shapes (the backgrounds), but you won't find a table. If the table is distributed over different pages, the "table" on one page won't know that it is related to the "table" on the other page.

Sure, you can add semantic structure to the document by introducing *marked content*, and by creating a *structure tree*, but that mechanism which we call Tagged PDF can't be used to make the PDF "editable" the same way a Word document is editable. Tagged PDF is (among others) used to allow assistive technology to present the content to the visually impaired (e.g. in the context of PDF/UA). The presence of structure doesn't change the fact that all text, all lines, and all shapes are added at *absolute positions*.

This is very different from HTML where the position on a page of a `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, or `<td>` is calculated at the moment the page is rendered. In HTML this position can even change when you resize the browser window.

There is no such thing in PDF (except if you use XFA (*), a technology that is deprecated since ISO 32000-2). All content on a page has a fixed position, hardcoded into the page's content stream. Changing the size of the PDF viewer window won't change anything to the position of the page content.

Because of all of this, your question is invalid. It is impossible to create a button in PDF that adds a row to a table, because:

1. In many cases there is no table: there is just a bunch of text, lines, and shapes at absolute positions,
2. Even if there is the notion of a table (using Tagged PDF): the visual represenation of that table is fixed at *creation time*, it can't be changed at *consumption time*.

You want to use an ordinary *PDF viewer* as if it were a *PDF editor*. That is impossible for all the reasons listed above.

(*) XFA was deprecated for different reasons. One of the most important reasons it is the lack of support for XFA. There aren't many viewers that support XFA. If you would post a follow-up question asking *"How can I create an XFA document?", the answer would be: *"Don't do this!"* Creating XFA is extremely complex, and once you've succeeded in creating an XFA form, you'll discover that many of your customers won't be able to consume the file because their viewer doesn't support the format.

Answer (score -1):

I also finding for this but didn't find over the internet. then i decide that i can learn this by using itextpdf documentation
in the documentation this is not clearly defined taht you can all rows dynamically in pdf table row/cell

but i have one way of add this, by using java code you can do this.

```
    Table table = new Table(rowData.length);

// get refrence of table 

// Add the row data to the table
for (String cellData : rowData) {
    table.addCell(new Cell().add(cellData));
}
```

i hope this code may help you.